# MySQL Select AND OR

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I'm not having success with my query statement and I think it has to do with the way I'm executing it.

```
$query5 = "select * from ".$db_prefix."customer_det where (fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."') or phone = '".$phone."'";
```

Essentially I want to select all from customer_det when the first and last name match the posted first and last name.  If there's no posted first and last name, then I want it to select all where the posted phone number matches.  My three variables $fname, $lname, and $phone are all set to read from the previous form $_POST['fname']; etc...

Is this the right logic to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right logic is not used, since its combined into 1 query. If only 1 query is used, it will search for `$fname=''` and `$lname=''` when neither of that is posted, along with the $phone part.

Try:

```
if( !empty($fname) && !empty($lname) )
  $query5 = "select * from ".$db_prefix."customer_det where (fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."')";
 else
    $query5 = "select * from ".$db_prefix."customer_det where phone = '".$phone."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

What your query is doing right now will return all rows where the names match and all rows where the phone number matches. If you want to only return rows where the phone number matches but only when the submitted first and last name are blank, you will need to add that to the where clause, like so:

```
$query5 = "select * from ".$db_prefix."customer_det where (fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."') or ('".$fname."' = '' and '".$lname."' = '' and phone = '".$phone."'");
```

This ensures that the phone number will only be used to match rows when the submitted first and last name are both blank, and doesn't require coding two separate queries.